# mod_rewrite showing a URL change although I can't see why

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mod-rewrite, passenger

I'm trying to simply get domain.net/abc to be passed to a Rails app as /s2?alt_url=abc and I don't want the URL to appear to have changed in the browser. I've been going around in circles with this for a long time now. I can get the rewrite to work (the app runs fine) but the URL is always swapped out in the browser.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /s2?alt_url=domain.net\%2F$1 [PT]
```

If I don't use [PT] then my final rule fails to pass correctly to the Rails app. I'm running Passenger and according to the discussion at http://code.google.com/p/phusion-passenger/issues/detail?id=230 I have to use [PT] and take care to not do anything else crazy. So I'm not sure why the pass through option forces an external redirect, but it seems to be necessary for this to work.

Does anybody know how I can avoid the URL changing without altering the Rails app?

Any help would be much appreciated.
Phil

Answer (score 0):

You obviously get an external redirect (HTTP 302 or similar), and you force that with [R]. I think you should simply remove [R].

[More about the R flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r).

**Update**  Ẁhen I think about it, changing domain names (to http://domain.net/home in this case) with always be an external redirect.

I suggest having separate rules for changing domain name and for handling various paths on the final domain name.

Comment: The [R] was there to redirect for pure http://domain.net/ requests without a specific page requested. But you did make me wonder whether this wasn't playing well with the other stuff. It wasn't that. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with rails but, this example should help you. this rewrite rule takes anything (alphanumeric, _ , and - ) after the the / ie. site.com/value

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /file.php?variable=$1
```

Where ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ is some regex I used to take anything after the url, and puts it in $1

This will leave your url as site.com/value

edit: an example of how I use this: [grwl.it/kirbdee](http://grwl.it/kirbdee), it leaves the url as is but underlyingly calls a php passing in kirbdee as a variable.

Comment: Kirby, this is a far cleaner rule. Thanks for that. It only works though if I add [PT]. Since I'm using Passenger to run my app it seems that there are some ways that it doesn't play well with mod_rewrite. Your cleaner rule helped me rule out the configuration and helped me get onto a new quest for answers on Google. Thanks.